# Derivative of matrix by a diagonal matrix

Tags: calculus, matrices

Let $F=ABC$ where $B=Diag(b)$. I know that by taking the derivative wrt $B$ results in $$\frac{\partial ABC}{\partial B}=(C^{T}\otimes A) $$
My question is, given that $B$ is a diagonal matrix, is there a simpler way to express the result?

Note. This work is part of a Taylor series expansion where the result will be multiplied by $\delta$ vec$(B)$. Knowing that $B$ is diagonal, I would like to reduce $\delta$ vec$(B)$ to a vector having the size of $b$. Basically, replacing $\delta$ vec$(B)$ by $\delta b$ since all other elements are zero.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It holds
$\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{ABC})
=\left( \mathbf{C}^T\otimes \mathbf{A} \right) \mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{B})$.

So the Jacobian is
$$
\frac{\partial \mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{ABC})}{\partial \mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{B}}
= \mathbf{C}^T\otimes \mathbf{A}
$$
Note that both numerator and denominator are vectors.

Since in your case $\mathbf{B}=\mathrm{diag}(\mathbf{b})$ is a diagonal matrix,
you can use
$\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{ABC})
=\left( \mathbf{C}^T \odot \mathbf{A} \right) \mathbf{b}$.
which involves the so-called Khatri-Rao matrix product.

Comment: Thanks for your answer